# How to log what is going on in then function angular2?

Tags: angular

I have the following in a function within my service:

```
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

My issue is, I want to actually log out what "response" is. When I do something like this, I get an error:

```
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
console.log(response);
response.json().data as Hero[];
})
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

What is the proper way for me to look at what is in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you forgot `return`:

```
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       return response.json().data as Hero[]; <== here
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Thanks. Just asking, would you use angular2 in production even though it is rc now?